# fullcalendar is not working on internet explorer 11

Tags: fullcalendar

i have json that containes two events.

On ie 11 the events renders on the same day,
one is on the 26/5/2014 and the other is in 27/5/2007

```
var myevents =[{"id":99,"title":"","start":"2014-05-26T07:30:00Z","end":"2014-05-26T13:00:00Z","color":"#fff","textColor":"#000","borderColor":"#000","allDay":false},{"id":101,"title":"","start":"2014-05-27T13:00:00Z","end":"2014-05-27T17:00:00Z","color":"#fff","textColor":"#000","borderColor":"#000","allDay":false}]

$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
header: {
    left: 'prev,next today',
    center: 'title',
    right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
},
editable: true,
year: 2014,
month: 4, 
events: function (start, end, callback) {
    //console.log(myevents);
    var obj = myevents//jQuery.parseJSON(myevents);
    var events = new Array();

    $.each(obj, function (index, value) {
        console.log(value)
        event = new Object();
        event.id = value['id']
        event.title = value['start'];//value['id'];
        event.start = value['start'];
        event.end = value['end'];
        event.color = value['color'];
        event.textColor = value['textColor'];
        event.borderColor = value['borderColor'];
        event.allDay = false;
        console.log(event);

        events.push(event);
    });
    callback(events);
}
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/hLw3W/2/
[image]

Comment: You should report any issues to the developer, see http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/wiki/Report-a-Bug/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem waw with the array.push
i changed the each loop to

```
 $.each(obj, function (index, value) {
                            events.push({
                                id: value['id'],
                                start: value['start'],
                                end: value['end'],
                                title: "",
                                color: value['color'],
                                textColor: value['textColor'],
                                borderColor: value['borderColor'],
                                allDay: false,
                                canSubscribe: value['canSubscribe']
                            });
                        });
```

and it's work fine